# codeigniter select list generated from database error when submitting the form

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a form which has 2 select box which also generate the options from database but the problem is when I do click on submit button the select box becomes empty.

here is the codes:

View:

```
    <ol class="breadcrumb-icon">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-inbox"></i> Add Courses</a></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Add Courses:</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="well">
                <?php if(isset($error)) echo $error;?>
                    <?php
                        $this->load->helper('form');

                        $attributes = array('role' => 'form','class'=>'form-horizontal');
                        echo form_open_multipart('admin/addcourses',$attributes);
                    ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course Category:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="category" class="form-control">
                                                <?php
                                                    foreach ($cat as $row)
                                                        {
                                                           echo "<option value='".$row->category_id."'>".$row->category_name."</option>";
                                                        }
                                                ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course Location:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="location" class="form-control">
                        <?php
                                                    foreach ($loc as $row)
                                                        {
                                                           echo "<option value='".$row->location_id."'>".$row->location_name."</option>";
                                                        }
                                                ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course Language:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="language" class="form-control">
                        <option value="English">English</option>
                        <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="coursename" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course Date:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="date" id="range-picker" readonly class="form-control kd-daterange">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course Image</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" name="course_image" class="upload" readonly class="form-control kd-upload">
                    <p>keep it empty to use the default image.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Course</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div> <!-- /.container laaast -->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/extended.min.js"></script>
<script>
    extended = new Extended();
</script>
```

Controller addcourses.php

```
public function addcourses()
    {
            if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) 
                {

                $this->load->model('admin/read_cat_loc');
                $data['cat']= $this->read_cat_loc->read_categories();
                $data['loc']= $this->read_cat_loc->read_locations();

                $this->load->view('admin/header_view');
                $this->load->view('admin/addcourses_view',$data);
                $this->load->view('admin/footer_view');
                }
            else {
                 redirect('admin/home');
                }
    }
```

model codes

class Read_cat_loc extends CI_Model {

```
public function read_categories() {

    $query= $this->db->get('course_category');

    return $query->result();
}


public function read_locations() {

    $query= $this->db->get('course_location');

    return $query->result();


}
```

}

Comment: I can't see `$cat` and `$loc` in your controller

Comment: opps .. wrong controller .. one second

Comment: You code seems correct, but what do you mean by "the select input becomes empty"

Comment: when I submit the form and returns to same form because of failure in inserting the data to database or file upload then it become empty.

Comment: I can't see the validation either in your function `admin/addcourses`

Answer (score 0):

ok solved:

I did this in main controller section :

```
            $this->load->model('admin/read_cat_loc');
            $data['cat']= $this->read_cat_loc->read_categories();
            $data['loc']= $this->read_cat_loc->read_locations();

            $this->load->view('admin/header_view');
            $this->load->view('admin/addcourses_view',$data);
            $this->load->view('admin/footer_view');
```

but in other areas where I have to reload the view I did this only:

```
            $this->load->view('admin/header_view');
            $this->load->view('admin/addcourses_view',$data);
            $this->load->view('admin/footer_view');
```

without the model part to retain the data again ...

If you know better way It will be great. Thanks

Comment: You mean within the constructor ?

Comment: no .. I did it in admin/addcourses where the submit button submits.

Comment: if you know better way .. Please share. Thanks